# make a Client-Server application

Tags: python, url, client-server, client, webclient

I used to create web app in the same computer, but if the server and the client is not in the same computer, how can we access to the web page ?

I mean, for example I have an html form and a button "ok" :
If the server and the client are in the same computer, in action = " " we put localhost/file.py , but if the server and the client are not in the same computer how to do this ? Because the client can't to have localhost in his webbrower (url).

Comment: Why can't you just use `action="<server_ip>/file.py"` where `<server_ip>` is the IP address of the computer the website is hosted on?

Comment: @pascalhein : but with server_ip I saw REMOTE_ADDR or socket.gethostname() but both returns localhost in the URL :( , I have a python server and I execute my python scripts in command line.

Comment: `socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), None)` will give you all configured IPs for your host, you have to pick the one your client has access to (so, if your server has the addresses `192.168.0.2` and `10.192.3.14`, and your client belongs only to `192.168.0.0/16`, you have to use the first of those two addresses)

Comment: I tried ip = REMOTE_ADDR, or socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gesthostname(), None) but I have already : localhost as URL :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is supposed to be run as a CGI script by a web-server, which sets environment variables like REMOTE_ADDR, REQUEST_METHOD ...

You are running the script by yourself, and this environment variable are not available.

That's why you get the KeyError.

Comment: OK I don't understand all of your response.

Answer (score 1):

The "action" part of a form is an url, and If you don't specify the scheme://host:port part of the URL, the client will resolve it has the current page one. IOW: just put the path part of your script's URL and you'll be fine. FWIW hardcoding the scheme://host:port of your URLs is an antipattern, as you just found out.

Comment: So, I have in one of my python file parameters and when I want to get IP address of the client with that IP = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]) and then I put ${IP} in action it return an error : File "./fileP.py", line 47, in <module>
    main(IP, name, city) 
  File "./fileP.py", line 22, in main
    IP = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'REMOTE_ADDR'
I don't understand.

Comment: It means that `REMOTE_ADDR` is not defined in the environment your script is executed in. BUT : you **dont** (I repeat: you **dont**) want the IP of the *client* as the url for your form's `action`.