# Use REMOTE_ADDR in an other file

Tags: python, html, client-server, global-variables, cgi

I code in python and I have a problem.
I have **file1.py :**

```
import os, sys, platform, getpass, tempfile
import webbrowser
import string
import json
import cgi, cgitb



def main( addr, name):
  os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"] = addr
  print os.environ ["REMOTE_ADDR"]

  template = open('file2.py').read() 

  tmpl = string.Template(template).substitute(
            name = name,
            addr = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]),
            os = user_os,
            user_name = user_login,
            )

  f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='/tmp/info.html', mode='w', delete=False)
  f.write(contenu)
  f.close()

  webbrowser.open(f.name)


 if __name__ == "__main__":
      addr = sys.argv[1]
      name = sys.argv[2]

  user_os = sys.platform
  sys.argv.append(user_os)

  user_login = getpass.getuser()
  sys.argv.append(user_login)

     main(addr, name)
```

in the **file2.py**

```
<form name="sD" method="get" action="${addr}">
```

but I have this error and I have tried to resolve it, but I don't know how can do that :(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./file1.py", line 47, in <module>
    main(addr, name) 
  File "./file1.py", line 22, in main
    addr = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'REMOTE_ADDR'
```

My problem is, I don't know how can I put a addr variable in command line and recover that IP address in an URL when I click on the OK button

Help me please :(

Comment: What is "this error"?

Comment: @TylerH : Sorry, I have edited the code and added the error.

Comment: @Andy : Please, if you want to help me -> help , otherwise let someone help me, thank you.

Comment: @Kasper, I've voted to close this question twice because it is a duplicate. This one is a duplicate of a duplicate. You aren't reading the answer provided. You didn't read the answer provided to this question. No one is telling you to add code to your python script. Perhaps you should google "How do I add an environment variable to <OS>" and replace <OS> with what ever operating system you are using.

Comment: @Kasper I answered the question on the other thread - you cannot do what you want - the env variable needs to be defined on a containing instance of the shell to be used across modules, because you don't get the answer you want doesn't mean its wrong.

Comment: @gkusner : An example is better than sentences.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems with your code.

First, as mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890739/make-a-client-server-application#comment38696080_24893137):

> you **dont** (I repeat: you **dont**) want the IP of the client as the url for
>   your form's action

What, exactly, do you think this line of code is going to do?

```
<form name="sD" method="get" action="${addr}">
```

It will attempt to send the form to your end user's IP address. **This will fail.** This will fail because

- They likely don't have a web server running
- Even if they do, they likely don't have a script built to handle your form
- You should be submitting the form to a page you control so that you can process it

As for your missing key error, you don't have an environment variable set. You can do this a few ways:

- From **outside of your python script**, use this command: `set REMOTE_ADDR=<value>`. Replace `<value>` with an appropriate value.
- From **within your python script**, use this code

Remember to import `os`

```
import os
os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"] = "value"
```

Again, `value` should be an appropriate value.

A very simple example of what you want:

```
import os, sys

def main( addr, name):
    os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"] = addr
    print os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    addr = sys.argv[1]
    name = sys.argv[2]

    main(addr, name)
```

This outputs:

```
>python test.py "address" "name"
address

>python test.py "http://www.google.com" "name"
http://www.google.com
```

Finally, as mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890739/make-a-client-server-application#comment38696080_24893137):

> you **dont** (I repeat: you **dont**) want the IP of the client as the url for
>   your form's action

Comment: So, I execute my script with parameters like this : /file1.py addr name, addr it's the address of the server ( = an URL ).

Comment: If that was a question...no. You don't execute your code like that, at least not with out looking at the code block I provided and making a change. Your `addr` needs to be assigned to the environment variable. `os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"] = addr`

Comment: That what I made in the substitute : addr = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]) ... I'm lost

Comment: You aren't reading what I wrote. Look, very carefully, at the code in both my answer and my comment. Notice which side of the equal sign `addr` is on. Notice the lack of `cgi.escape` in my code.

Comment: because if I made os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"] = addr ..... it will not work because addr is no defined, but addr is a variable to fill in commande line when I execute my script, you understand ?

Comment: @Kasper, no, I don't understand. Look at what I added. It works exactly as I described. I didn't touch your `if __name__` block, or the `main` definition. You'll see that `addr` is passed exactly as it should be because the `print` statement I added in `main` outputs the `addr` value as it should.

Comment: So, in subsitute you don't have addr = os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"], but how can we have the client IP into an URL ? And if I do your syntax I have this "big error" : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./file1.py", line 49, in <module>
    main(addr, name) 
  File "./file1", line 23, in main
    user_name = user_login,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/string.py", line 172, in substitute
    return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/string.py", line 162, in convert
    val = mapping[named]
KeyError: 'addr' I'll edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

From your shell (i.e. command line)

```
$> set REMOTE_ADDR=<some url>

$> python
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
<some url>
```

if you define it in the python instance it is only available to that instance

but by putting in the 'environment' before calling any module it is 'globally' available

Comment: I'm not using the python terminal, but if I have this when I try : >>> import os
>>> print os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'REMOTE_ADDR'

Comment: Yes it needs to be set and it needs to be set to a value. I used the python terminal to illustrate the concept - it like any module inherits the parent processes' environment. Setting an env value in a module does not put it into the parents' environment.

Comment: But you declare your set before starting python .... honnestly I'm lost .... you and Andy spoke about value, but I don't understand because REMOTE_ADDR  is to get the client IP, and when I use REMOTE_ADDR in the same file it works but if I call it in other file it doesn't works , addr parameter ( in command line ) is the IP of the client he filled it in command line and I just want to recover this addr in URL when we click on a button to going to the next web page, that's all :(

Comment: OK looking at the code REMOTE_ADDR is undefined because it was never defined externally, but you don't need it you are getting the address as a parm so forget all that environment stuff and simply do tmpl = string.Template(template).substitute(
            name = name,
            addr = cgi.escape(addr)
            )

Comment: I defined addr = os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"] before def main , and in substitute I make : tmpl = string.Template(template).substitute( name = name, addr = cgi.escape(addr) ) but I have this error ... again : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./file1.py", line 10, in <module>
    addr = os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'REMOTE_ADDR'

Comment: Get rid of ALL references to REMOTE_ADDR including the first one.

Comment: Why ? Get the REMOTE_ADDR is what I want :(

Comment: OK I give up - it isn't working for you but you must be right. You are using a parm not an env variable but somehow you think otherwise, I can't give you anymore guidance.